# How to implements TypeScript's interface for function?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I want to define interface with function overloads and implement it.

I can do this:

```ts
export interface ServerRoutHandler
{
  ( opts: any, handlers: RequestHandler );
  ( opts: any, handlers: RequestHandler[] );
  ( opts: any, ...handlers: RequestHandler[] );
  ( opts: any, handlers: RequestCtxHandler );
  ( opts: any, handlers: RequestCtxHandler[] );
  ( opts: any, ...handlers: RequestCtxHandler[] );
}
```

and then this

```ts
get:ServerRoutHandler = ( opts: any, ...handlers: any[] ) =>
{
  return this.factoryRouts('GET', opts, handlers);
}

post:ServerRoutHandler = ( opts: any, ...handlers: any[] ) =>
{
  return this.factoryRouts('POST', opts, handlers);
}

del:ServerRoutHandler = ( opts: any, ...handlers: any[] ) =>
{
  return this.factoryRouts('DELETE', opts, handlers);
}
```

But it seems more as workaround and slightly changes the behavior of the function.

Is there another syntax? Like this:

```ts
get<ServerRoutHandler>( opts: any, ...handlers: any[] )
{
  return this.factoryRouts('GET', opts, handlers);
}
// It's not works as expected
```

Comment: What you do mean by "slightly changes the behavior of the function"? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @Louis, if I implement this in class, its will be property, not a function.

Answer (score -1):

The way you do it, if you implement `get`, `post` and `del` in a class, they will actually be functions and callable. The only issue I see is that the way you do it, `this` has no definite type in those functions and thus accessing it can be a problem. However, if you specify the type of `this` as the first argument, it takes care of the problem. Note that this initial `this` argument does not add a new parameter to your function, it is there only to tell TypeScript what the type of `this` is. Here's an example:

```
// I don't have your types. So I'm setting these to strings to that the code compiles.
type RequestHandler = string;
type RequestCtxHandler = string;

interface ServerRouteHandler {
  (opts: any, handlers: RequestHandler );
  (opts: any, handlers: RequestHandler[] );
  (opts: any, ...handlers: RequestHandler[] );
  (opts: any, handlers: RequestCtxHandler );
  (opts: any, handlers: RequestCtxHandler[] );
  (opts: any, ...handlers: RequestCtxHandler[] );
}

// Example class that has methods that fit ServerRouteHandler
class Something {
    constructor(public x: number) { }

    get: ServerRouteHandler = function get(this: Something, opts: any, ...handlers: any[]) {
        console.log("get", this.x, opts, handlers);
    }
}

const something = new Something(999);
something.get({}, ["1"]);
```

If you run this, you get `get 999 Object Array[1]` on the console.

I'm not aware of a syntax that would be more straightforward.